# Не работают вместе два LinkPager в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, виджет, pjax

Проект на Yii2 + AngularJS. На странице два GridView + LinkPager обернутые в два разных pjax контейнера, два разные dataProvider для гридов и пагинации. У контейнеров разные id, в ангуляровском контроллере прописаны конструкции по обновлению после завершения pjax:

```
$("#p0").on("pjax:end", function() {
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById("p0")))($scope);
});
$("#p1").on("pjax:end", function() {
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById("p1")))($scope);
});
```

Первый контейнер работает, но когда кликаешь по элементам второго пагинатора, то он обновляет контент только первого контейнера. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в параметрах контейнера:

```
    <?php Pjax::begin([
        'enablePushState' => false,
        'linkSelector' => 'ul.pagination>li>a'
    ]); ?>
```

Я убрал параметр linkSelector у обоих контейнеров и все заработало. [Описание](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax#$linkSelector-detail) зачем нужно это свойство.